# Why does ScriptBlock convert Hashtable to Collection and how to avoid it?

Tags: powershell, hashtable, scriptblock

Consider this PowerShell script:

```bsh
[Hashtable] $t = @{} 
function foo($x) { $x }
$t2 = foo $t
$t3 = {param([Hashtable] $x) [Hashtable]$x}.Invoke($t)
$t4 = $function:foo.Invoke($t)
Write-Host "argument type              " $t.GetType()
Write-Host "function call              " $t2.GetType()
Write-Host "script block Invoke        " $t3.GetType()
Write-Host "function variable Invoke   " $t4.GetType()
```

Which outputs:

```
argument type              System.Collections.Hashtable
function call              System.Collections.Hashtable
script block Invoke        System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]
function variable Invoke   System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]
```

Why does the script block return a `Collection` instead of a `Hashtable`?
How to make the script block return a `Hashtable`?

PowerShell version used:

```bsh
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.0.0
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.0.0
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.18363
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Comment: It looks like you've already answered your own question. [MethodBase.Invoke Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?view=netcore-3.1)  Invokes the method or constructor reflected by this MethodInfo instance.
   [PowerShell.Invoke Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.invoke?view=pscore-6.2.0)  Invoke() --- Invoke the Command synchronously and return the output PSObject collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at `InvokeReturnAsIs` method:

```
[Hashtable] $t = @{} 
function foo($x) { $x }
$t2 = foo $t
$t3 = {param([Hashtable] $foo) [Hashtable]$foo}.InvokeReturnAsIs($t)
Write-Host $t.GetType()
Write-Host $t2.GetType()
Write-Host $t3.GetType()
```

Which outputs:

```
System.Collections.Hashtable
System.Collections.Hashtable
System.Collections.Hashtable
```

It seems to give the result you are looking for, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invokereturnasis?view=pscore-6.2.0) does not give much informations

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `Hashtable` gets converted to `Collection` due to a call of the [ScriptBlock.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invoke?view=pscore-6.2.0) method. Its return type is `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.Management.Automation.PSObject>`.

Looks like this can be circumvented by invoking the script block via [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7):

```bsh
[Hashtable] $t = @{} 
$t5 = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {param([Hashtable] $x) [Hashtable]$x} -ArgumentList $t
$t6 = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $function:foo -ArgumentList $t
Write-Host "Invoke-Command on script block      " $t5.GetType()
Write-Host "Invoke-Command on function variable " $t6.GetType()
```

This outputs:

```bsh
Invoke-Command on script block        System.Collections.Hashtable
Invoke-Command on function variable   System.Collections.Hashtable
```